# Google Custom Device Action Giving Error on Raspberry Pi Google Assistant

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I'm creating a google assistant on my Raspberry Pi 3 and I'm trying to create a custom device action to eventually open my garage door. All it does is play with an LED at this point in time.

Here is my actions.json file:

```
{
    "manifest": {
        "displayName": "Garage door",
        "invocationName": "Garage door",
        "category": "PRODUCTIVITY"
    },
    "actions": [
        {
            "name": "me.custom.actions.GarageDoor",
            "availability": {
                "deviceClasses": [
                    {
                        "assistantSdkDevice": {}
                    }
                ]
            },
            "intent": {
                "name": "me.custom.intents.GarageDoor",
                "trigger": {
                    "queryPatterns": [
                        "open the garage door",
                        "close the garage door"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "fulfillment": {
                "staticFulfillment": {
                    "templatedResponse": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "simpleResponse": {
                                    "textToSpeech": "Okay"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "deviceExecution": {
                                    "command": "me.custom.commands.GarageDoor"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "types": []
}
```

But when I run the command I get this error:

```
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "open the garage door".
INFO:root:Playing assistant response.
WARNING:root:Error during command execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/assistant-sdk-python/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/device_helpers.py", line 94, in dispatch_command
    self.handlers[command](**params)
TypeError: gdoor() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
```

Here's my handler:

```
@device_handler.command('me.custom.commands.GarageDoor')
    def gdoor(*args):
        print(args)
        global g_open
        if g_open:
            GPIO.output(18, 0)
            g_open = 0
        else:
            GPIO.output(18, 1)
            g_open = 1
```

I was playing around with the *args to see if it fixed anything - it didn't. I've changed my package names to custom just for privacy. I'm quite confused here. Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py#L428), it seems like the function signature is a bit different, as it directly adds the arguments.

```
@device_handler.command('com.example.commands.BlinkLight')
def blink(speed, number):
    logging.info('Blinking device %s times.' % number)
    delay = 1
    if speed == "SLOWLY":
        delay = 2
    elif speed == "QUICKLY":
        delay = 0.5
    for i in range(int(number)):
        logging.info('Device is blinking.')
        time.sleep(delay)
```

Looking at the action package, it doesn't seem like you're providing any actions to go along with the command fulfillment. As shown in [the sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/actions.json#L45):

```
{
    "deviceExecution": {
        "command": "com.example.commands.BlinkLight",
        "params": {
            "speed": "$speed",
            "number": "$number"
        }
    }
}
```

Without any params, it may not map any functions at all.